# Formula to apportion amount in columns

Tags: excel

I have a monthly timeline in columns and I am using this formula to apportion an amount in equal installments in each month.

```
IF(AND(DATEVALUE(Z$9)>=EOMONTH($D44,1),DATEVALUE(Z$9)<=EDATE(EOMONTH($D44,1),$D45)),$E45/$D45,0)

D44 = Start Date
D45 = number of months
```

However, this doesn't work for 5 months lets say. It gives 6 installments instead of 5.

Comment: strangely enough it works if number of months is 1,3,4...

Comment: I must be missing something here... You have x amount of money you need to apportion over y number of months... isn't that simply x / y ? If not, please explain. Is it because a customer might have started the account in the middle of a month and you need to still evenly apportion the payments?

Comment: i need to delay apportionment by 1 month, that's why I have EOMONTH(D44,1) .. is that what causes the problem ?

Comment: I will take another crack at it tomorrow, but for now a more efficient function evaluates using modulus algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(W9<=EOMONTH($D44,$D45),W9>EOMONTH($D44,0)),$E45/$D45,"")
```

copied across to suit.